# What is the difference between HSPA vs HSPAP

Tags: android, mobile, protocols

The Android API responds network type returns "HSPA" which I understand as High Speed Packet Access. However, I also see HSPAP at times and I would like to know the difference with the extra "P".

In case it matters I am seeing this on BLU phones.

Answer (score 6):

GPRS(114Kbps) < EGDE(368Kbps) < 3G(3.1Mbps) < HSPA(14Mbps) < HSPA+(168Mbps) < 4G/LTE(299.6Mbps)

HSPA include HSUPA (Upload) & HSDPA (Download)

HSPAP & HSPA+ are the same

Answer (score 0):

HSPA (High Speed Packet Access) is a mobile telephony technology that allows for data transmission speeds up to 21 Mbps. HSPA+ (also called Evolved HSPA or 4G) is a further evolution of HSPA that offers data speeds of up to 42 Mbps.

Comment: HSPAP/+ (also called Evolved HSPA or 4G) is a further evolution of HSPA that offers data speeds of up to 42 Mbps.